# UATA hard disk and IDE/SATA to USB bridge

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I have a UATA hard disk and an IDE/SATA to USB bridge. Whenever I connect my hard disk it does not run, but when I do not connect the data cable but only the power the hard disk drive is running? What do I need to do to use this hard disk externally?

Answer (score 0):

That always used to be what happened when you plugged the HDD end of the cable in upside down (half the cable is ground IIRC) but I think modern cables have enough cut-outs you can't do that.

Are you definitely connecting it the right way around, the red stripe to pin 1? At both ends?